# Server.MapPath in window open in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, popup, window

i want to open a new pop up window when user click the button.But nw i facing a problem, how can i open  a new pop up window based on server.mapPath?
Here is my coding

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script>");


        sb.Append("window.open(" + Server.MapPath("~/reportPreview.aspx") + ", '', '');");
        sb.Append("</script>");


        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"test", sb.ToString());
```

But i cant open a new window . Please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.open` expects a URL like "../reportPreview.aspx", but `Server.MapPath` returns a physical path like "C:\YourApp\reportPreview.aspx". You should call `ResolveClientUrl` instead. Also, you need to add quotes around the URL:

```
sb.Append("window.open('" + ResolveClientUrl("~/reportPreview.aspx") + "', '', '');");
```